# How to format a string in XAML where a binding is being used?

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

In WPF, I could do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Products.Count, StringFormat='{0} Products'}"
```

What is the equivalent in Windows 8 / WinRT, as this syntax is no longer supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation on MSDN this functionality (e.g `StringFormat` on the [Binding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.aspx)) is not existing in WinRT.

So do the formatting on your ViewModel

```csh
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public string ProductsText 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return string.Format("{0} Products", Products.Count); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Note you can hook to track changes in your `Products` collection and notify the `ProductsText` property changed.

And bind to formatted property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductsText}" />
```

Comment: Or you can write a `IValueConverter` or use a `ContentControl` and build your text from multiple parts, and I guess there are multiple ways, but I strongly advise to do it on the viewmodel. Because Viewmodels are meant for this.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Products.Count}" />
    <Run Text=" Products" />
</TextBlock>
```